# Ajax Captcha control image changing values at post back time using ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

Ajax Captcha control image changing values when select any values from dropdown list, auto post back issue using ASP.NET C#. Captcha image should not be change when select any value from drop down list. And i am using ddl_years_SelectedIndexChanged event. And below is drop downlist and ajax captcha control design.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
       <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_years" runat="server"    AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="Exp"
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_years_SelectedIndexChanged">
 <asp:ListItem Value="0">Year</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="1">0</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="2">1</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="3">2</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="4">3</asp:ListItem>
       </asp:DropDownList>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
     <cc1:CaptchaControl ID="CaptchaControl1" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="None"
     CaptchaHeight="40" CaptchaLength="5" CaptchaLineNoise="None" CaptchaMaxTimeout="240" 
           CaptchaMinTimeout="5" FontColor="111, 109, 85" Width="325px" CaptchaWidth="300"
            CssClass="textarea_captha" />
      </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Ajax Captcha control design:

```
 <cc1:CaptchaControl ID="CaptchaControl1" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="None"
  CaptchaHeight="40" CaptchaLength="5" CaptchaLineNoise="None" CaptchaMaxTimeout="240" 
    CaptchaMinTimeout="5" FontColor="111, 109, 85" Width="325px" CaptchaWidth="300"  CssClass="textarea_captha" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `CaptchaControl1` control is doing or how it refreshes the image but my gut feeling is that you only need to refresh/present the image on the first page load...

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if(!IsPostBack)
      CaptchaControl1.Method_that_refreshes_the_image();
}
```

This assumes that `CaptchaControl1` is a user/server control and that the captcha image state is saved across postbacks.

Another options is setting the `UpdatePanel4`'s `UpdateMode` property to `Conditional`

Comment: `Ajax Captcha Control` doesn't say much there are a lot of third-parties out there. But, still, because of the html markup the answer still stands

Comment: what control are you using? @mohdmazharkhan

Comment: So i have go for html markup for resolve this issue, can you observe my markup. Already did so many changes for result but still face this issue.

Comment: Ok, your question pretty much the same and you are still failing to provide information about which CAPTCHA control you are using. I've updated my answer if that doesn't solve anything I'll remove the answer

Comment: I had used .cs code like that,  CaptchaControl1.ValidateCaptcha(txtCaptcha.Text.Trim());
 
  if (!CaptchaControl1.UserValidated)
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Not Valid Captcha!');", true);
                        return;
                    }

Comment: i am using captcha:  <%@ Register Assembly="MSCaptcha" Namespace="MSCaptcha" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

Comment: Thanks got answer is UpdateMode property to Conditional.